# Passing multiple arguments in bash (without getopt)

Tags: bash

I have a bash script I am working on where I need to pass two arguments into a function. When I run the script everything works fine, except when it parses through the file I pass to it, the result I always get is `Association` (this is written in the text file). Can you advise what I would need to do so that it parses the correct info, which should be what I would type in as uid? I wrote in the input `123456789` because that's in the text file, but again I am getting `Association` as the result instead.

```
echo "Please enter the UID: ";
read uid

echo "Please enter server file: ";
read server
uidAssoc(){
            arg1=$1
            arg2=$2
            for arg1 in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do awk 'match($i, $2){ print substr($i, RSTART, RLENGTH)} ' ~/jlog/"$2";done;}
    uidAssoc "$uid" "$server"
    exit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closing brace of the function **requires** whitespace in front of it ([reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping)). Formatting your code more readably will help.

```
uidAssoc(){
    arg1=$1
    arg2=$2
    for arg1 in $(cat ~/jlog/"$2"); do
        awk 'match($i, $2){ print substr($i, RSTART, RLENGTH)} ' ~/jlog/"$2"
    done
}
```

Some questions for you:

- Why do you assign `arg1` and `arg2` but never use them?
- What is `$i` in your awk script? (since `i` is unset, that will eventually evaluate to the whole line)
- Are you aware that the `$2` inside single quotes is different from the `$2` outside of single quotes?

Comment: For `arg1` and `arg2`, they are used as local variables for the paramters. For `$i`, I used the match function in awk and it required some arguments. As for `$2`, I am aware of the differences betweetn single and double quotes. I am still kind of novice so I had to tweak the script around a bit.